# Formatting of an XP/Vista dual boot machine now unable to boot up XP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, multi-boot

My laptop dual boots Vista Home Premium and Windows XP.

I have Vista on the C drive and XP on the D drive. I formatted Vista and installed Windows 7 over it.

Problem is that I'm now unable to boot XP.

I've tried to boot with the XP installation disk, but no luck, the repair option is not available.

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to follow [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) to fix your mbr.

You could also try installing [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) and seeing if XP pops up in the options there.