# Formatted C: from Windows 7 setup, now it won't even install

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, installation, mbr

Help, I'm so confused. I did more or less what's been described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/117076/formatting-of-an-xp-vista-dual-boot-machine-now-unable-to-boot-up-xp):

I formatted Vista and installed Windows 7 over it. Problem is that I'm now unable to boot

- I'm installing Windows 7 on top of Vista
  on an ACER AS1410 Notebook
- When it
  comes to the part where I choose
  where to install, I pick the
  partition labeled C:\ but instead of
  keeping windows.old files (what would
  I want them for?)
- I choose to go and carelessly 
  format the partition (my bad). It
  shows me this error:

  > Setup was unable to create a new system partition or locate an existing system partition. See the Setup log files for more information.
- Now the only option is "Load Driver".
  I have tried installing every single one from
  ACER website, none of them are
  useful. I even flashed the original BIOS.

I've tried going back and choose "Repair" like in the picture:
[image]

but I only get an error:

> Failed to save startup options.

I think this is weird, what else can I do?

Comment: I'm tempted to recover from hidden Acer partition, but not right now. Atm I'm delving into bootrec and bcdedit (can someone explain the difference between those two?). I'm very curious and I want to learn something from this incident, if anything.

Comment: Install Ubuntu instead?

Comment: @marcusw you realize your comment is mostly useless, don't you? Not everyone is willing to make such a leap, so either you help them overcome their problem or try to help someone else.

Comment: +1 for really trying to prove some info on your problem

Comment: Thanks! I did an update here= http://superuser.com/questions/124699/the-bcdedit-export-operation-fails-windows-vista-not-booting

Comment: @marcusw well, I just downloaded Ubuntu Karmic, installed without any problm, then rebooted and a black screen with the logo welcomed me, hung there for ~5 min then the blue Caps Lock LED on the keyboard started flashing continuously. Safe mode just tells me it gave up waiting for root device. So no luck there either :(((

Answer (score 2):

Delete the partition, then skip format, just choose the unformatted partition as the target, let Windows 7 setup do the rest.

.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [forum post](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7repair/thread/e2f50f68-a49a-4936-8ca6-8d920557262a) with a similiar problem and they have several suggestions using the bootrec.exe tool on the Windows 7 Disc.

Comment: of course, it goes ok up until 3. bootrec /RebuildBCD, since I formatted the disk, Vista is nowhere to be found. Should I run some command prompt-compatible recovery solution? if so, which do you recommend? (preferably foss?) thanks

Comment: there's nothing on C: but a Temp folder with the following files (6, 14K): bcdinfo.txt bootfailure.txt disklayout.txt srtTrail.log StrTrail.txt uploadrecord.txt

Answer (score 0):

Boot from Hiren's Boot Disc, format the partition as you'd like it, and then start the installation again. This time Leave the file-system intact.

This problem occurred to me too.

Comment: ok so Hiren's boot cd has a million apps or so, which one should recover my vista old files?

Comment: Recovering the data is a hit n try process! The CD is divided into sections there's an entire section for Recovery Tools. Use each one turn by turn if you don't get what you're looking for in the first hit!
I'd suggest Recuva - Available on the disc.

Comment: I'll try that bc it's free. First I'll try to recover bootmgr, wish me luck.

Comment: BTW I didn't know I was messing with the file-system when I formatted from setup, I thought the setup would handle it fine and even, optimize it for Win7. *sigh* who knew.

Comment: @ocurro, what's the status, how are things now?

Comment: Just finished downloading Hiren's. Slow connection. I also had to figure out the download links, as they are as inconspicuos as possible. OK, first try was  TestDisk, hangs on Scanning USBs. Second try...